# Would a giant satellite laser work as a weapon?

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, astrophysics, sun, satellites

If someone built a satellite to float about in space, which used mirrors to focus and magnify energy from the sun directly into one direct spot (like in the James Bond film [*Die Another Day*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0246460/)) would it actually work? Could it be powerful enough to destroy buildings and burn through the ground?

Or is it not possible? And if not, why?

Answer (score 2):

## **Very Short and Quick Answer**

Yes, it is possible so long as one has a large enough set of mirrors and the focal points are determined accurately enough (ignoring heat dissipation, which might be an issue in space).  There is a [solar furnace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_furnace) in France that does just this, though it is based on ground and has on the order of 10,000 mirrors, each of which appears to be quite large.

The [Mega Watt Solar Furnace](https://www.promes.cnrs.fr/index.php?page=mega-watt-solar-furnace), for instance, has a total collecting area of 2835 m<sup>2</sup> and it focuses the beam of light into a spot roughly 80 cm in diameter (i.e., ~0.503 m<sup>2</sup>)

## **Longer Answer with Background and Examples**

The [sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun) emits at [Earth's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth) orbit roughly [1380 W/m<sup>2</sup>](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/sunfact.html), so you can determine the necessary collecting area based upon the target you wish to destroy.  In the movie, the beam was shown to have a rather large diameter, but let's assume (to make the numbers easy to deal with) that area over which the *death ray* fires is 1 m<sup>2</sup>.  Therefore, assuming no losses in the focusing or transmission through the atmosphere and no frequency conversion, one would have a gain factor in power of roughly 1400 for every square meter of collecting area on the spacecraft.

So what you want to do in this case is look at the [heat of sublimation](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Thermodynamics/State_Functions/Enthalpy/Heat_of_Sublimation) (also called the *enthalpy of sublimation*), $\Delta$H<sub>sub</sub>, for various materials.  This is the required energy necessary to turn a given [solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid) into a [gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas) without transitioning through the [liquid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid) phase, a process called [sublimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublimation_(phase_transition)).

There is an exhaustive list of $\Delta$H<sub>sub</sub> values for numerous organic molecules from NIST in this [PDF](http://www.nist.gov/data/PDFfiles/jpcrd618.pdf).  You can look on most Wikipedia pages for the [heat of vaporization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization), $\Delta$H<sub>vap</sub>, which is always less than $\Delta$H<sub>sub</sub>.  Say, for example, we look at [aluminum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium) or Al, $\Delta$H<sub>vap</sub> ~ 284 kJ/mol (kilojoules per [mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit))) and its $\Delta$H<sub>sub</sub> ~ [326 kJ/mol](http://www.chemicool.com/elements/aluminum.html) (called [*heat of atomization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_atomization) in this case).  Al has a density of ~2.7 g/cm<sup>3</sup> (or 2700 kg/m<sup>3</sup>) and an atomic mass of ~26.98154 g/mol.  Thus, one mole of Al should have a mass of ~26.98154 g and occupy a volume of ~9.9932 $cm^{3}$ (recall that 1 cm<sup>3</sup> is one milliliter).

## **Examples**

### **Example 1**

So now let's put those numbers to use.

- Let's say our spacecraft had a collecting area of 1000 m<sup>2</sup>, just to make the numbers easy, and perfect mirrors (i.e., no losses).
- That means the spacecraft would be collecting a total of ~1,380,000 watts of power (recall:  1 W = 1 J/s) or ~1.38 MW.
- Focusing that into a 1 m<sup>2</sup> beam means our power density is ~1.38 MW/m<sup>2</sup>.
- So how much Al could we vaporize in one second (again, to make the numbers easy) if it were distributed over a nice circular disk with an area of 1 m<sup>2</sup>?

For now, let's ignore the angles of incidence and all those complications.  Then we need only divide our power density, call it $\Delta$S, by the $\Delta$H<sub>vap</sub> value and the area, $A$, to get the total number of moles, which we can use to determine the total mass and volume.  This is given mathematically by:
$$
Moles \ of \ Al = \left( \frac{ \Delta S }{ \Delta H_{sub} * A } \right) \sim \left( \frac{ 1.38 \times 10^{6} \ J \ m^{-2} \ s^{-1} }{ 384 \times 10^{3} \ J \ mol^{-1} } \right) \sim 3.59 \ \text{moles}
$$
which corresponds to ~96.965 g of Al or a ~35.913 cm<sup>3</sup> volume.  This is only ~$3.591 \times 10^{-5}$ m<sup>3</sup> or a 1 m<sup>2</sup> that is only ~35 $\mu$m thick (i.e., roughly half the thickness of a typical human hair).

### **Example 2**

Perhaps a better way to ask this question is to start with a given amount of Al (you can do this with any material, just change the numbers) and work backwards to determine the amount of power density needed.

- Let's say we have a 1 m<sup>2</sup> disk again, but now it's 1 foot thick (or ~0.3048 m), corresponding to a total volume of ~0.3048 m<sup>3</sup>.
- This means we have ~822.96 kg of Al or ~30500.854 moles.
- From the known value of $\Delta$H<sub>sub</sub>, this means we need ~11.712 GJ of energy to sublime the Al disk (recall 1 GJ = $10^{9}$ J).
- To do this in one second with a 1 m<sup>2</sup> beam means we need $\Delta$S ~ 11.712 GW/m<sup>2</sup>.
- We know the sun's power density output at Earth is ~1380 W/m<sup>2</sup>, so we just divide these two numbers to get the amount of collecting area needed to vaporize our Al disk.  The area turns out to be ~$8.5 \times 10^{6}$ m<sup>2</sup>, which seems a little unreasonable, since one of the largest buildings by volume is the [Boeing Everett Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Everett_Factory) at only ~400,000 m<sup>2</sup>.

**Side Note:**  The one advantage about having a mirror system like this in space is that one need not worry about inter-mirror stresses/strains (except during any orbital maneuver, obviously).  However, that is hardly a significant enough advantage to actually make this worthwhile or feasible.

### **Example 3**

- Let's try using the beam size of the *Mega Watt Solar Furnace*, i.e., ~0.503 m<sup>2</sup> for our focusing point and again use a 1 ft thick piece of Al, i.e., a ~0.1532 m<sup>3</sup> volume.
- This corresponds to ~413.66 kg of Al, or ~15,331.40 moles of Al.
- Thus, we need ~5 GJ of energy to sublime the Al disk.
- A 5 GJ beam covering ~0.503 m<sup>2</sup> for a one second duration corresponds to $\Delta$S ~ 9.9 GW/m<sup>2</sup>.
- Therefore, to generate this energy density we would need a collecting area of ~$3.6 \times 10^{6}$ m<sup>2</sup>, which is still unreasonably large.

## **Long Answer Conclusion**

Yes it is theoretically possible, but it is neither feasible nor practical.

Is the example from the movie accurate or even possible?  I would wager no!